# jCanvas - Drag n Drop when scaling

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, scale, jcanvas

I have painted a canvas with different layers. If I zoom the canvas, then no longer correct positions. But I want to be able to zoom, without any postponements. The canvas itself is zoomed.

This is my function:

```
function zoomCanvas(diff){
  $("#myCanvas").scaleCanvas({
    x: 0, y: 0,
    scaleX: diff, scaleY: diff
  })
  .drawLayers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are working with jCanvas layers on your canvas, the canvas needs to be scaled whenever layers are redrawn.

Therefore, you must make make your `scaleCanvas()` call into a jCanvas layer (yes, you can actually do this) by setting its `layer` property to `true`.

```
$("#myCanvas").scaleCanvas({
    layer: true,
    name: "zoom", // give layer a name so we can easily retrieve it later
    x: 0, y: 0,
    scale: 1 // set its scale factor to 1 
});
```

However, in order for this to work properly, you should create this `scaleCanvas` layer before all other layers, and then you can later change its `scale` property layer.

```
// Function for setting zoom level of canvas
function zoomCanvas(diff) {
    // Update zoom level
    $("#myCanvas").setLayer('zoom', {
        scale: diff
    })
    // Redraw canvas
    .drawLayers();
}
```

*BTW, the `scale` property that I'm using in my examples changes both the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties that you are using in yours; the `scale` property simply exists for convenience.*

Finally, here is [a working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/caleb531/qYBCL/) that implements all of this.